# find a counterexample or a proof for the given conjectures.

Tags: logic

If $x$ is a factor of $y$, then $x\le y$.

I figured that I have to let $x$ be a factor of $y$ such that $y=xk$ for some integer $k$. But I'm not sure what I should be doing next.

Comment: What set are $x$ and $y$ in? If they are (positive) natural numbers, the statement is true, but if they are integers, then as 5xum points out below, the statement is false.

Comment: There isn't a given set to the problem.

Comment: In that case go with 5xum's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Try to find a counterexample. Think about what happens if $y$ is negative.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. I think I was just thinking too hard about it.